# getsubimage() function in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

this is my code :

```
        for (int ii = 0; ii <= 17; ii++) {
        System.out.println(ii);
        if(ii == 10) continue;
        String name = String.valueOf(ii);
        File pic = new File(name + ".jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(pic); 
        int w ;
        int h ;
        int x_max = 0;
        int x_min = 1000;
        int y_max = 0;
        int y_min = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
                Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
                if(c.getBlue() == 0){
                    x_max = Math.max(x_max, i);
                    x_min = Math.min(x_min, i);
                    y_max = Math.max(y_max, j);
                    y_min = Math.min(y_min, j);
                }

            }
        }

        BufferedImage imagea = image;
        image = imagea.getSubimage(x_min - 1, y_min - 1,x_max - x_min + 3 , y_max - y_min + 3);
        h = Math.abs(y_max - y_min);
        w = Math.abs(x_max - x_min);}
```

and this is output :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside of Raster
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
    at element.main(element.java:41)
```

the error is about "getsubimage" function but i dont know its reason.
the code work until eighth image and dont work for it.
how work "getsubimage" function in java?

Comment: `(x + width) is outside of Raster` is your reason.

Comment: I know this but why? (x + width) must be in image

Comment: Find out why: run your code in a debugger and inspect the key variables as it's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
image = imagea.getSubimage(x_min - 1, y_min - 1,x_max - x_min + 3 , y_max - y_min + 3);
```

Assumes that the resulting coordinates are at least 1 pixel offset from the left and upper edge, and 3 pixels offset from the left and bottom edge. Don't assume that, or make sure they will.

Comment: This is not its reason. the program work for first seven image.

Comment: I'll have to disappoint you, because it really really is the reason. Add some debug printing: the dimensions of the image, and the coordinates you want to crop.

Comment: I edited it to  image = imagea.getSubimage(x_min, y_min,x_max - x_min, y_max - y_min); but the compiler show that error again.

Comment: One last possibility could be that there is no single pixel without blue. So that the min values are still 1000 when it ends.

Comment: that is right. i print the coordinates and find out this. Thank a lot